# Unable to find explicit activity class {com.miui.sercuritycenter/com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity} MIUI 11

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, permissions, xiaomi

```
if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("Xiaomi")) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
            intent.setClassName("com.miui.sercuritycenter","com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
            intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());
            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            return;
        } catch (Exception ignore){
            Log.d("Xiaomi", "first fails");
        }
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
            intent.setClassName("com.miui.sercuritycenter","com.miui.permcenter.permissions.AppPermissionsEditorActivity");
            intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());
            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            return;
        } catch (Exception ignore){
            Log.d("Xiaomi", "second fails");
        }

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:" +  this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName()));
        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 2084);
   }
```

this code result this exception

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.miui.sercuritycenter/com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

why?

Comment: Found any solution for this?